# CLLocation Manager (How Enable "Use current Location")

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

I am trying to access user current Location.When i call CLLocationManager(startUpdating).

Its show alertview ex. "Xyz App would like to use your current location".
If user taps "Dont allow". and now if i check authorization status it reply 2 "means Denied".
I check status and if its 2(means denied),  i show showalertview "Xyz want to use your current location"

Now if user Taps "Allow" how to enabled it programmatically,instead of user goes to setting screen & manually enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not enable programmatically it the user taps don't allow. You just can inform the user that he has to go to settings->Location Services and enable it for your app if he wants to use this feature.

You can set the [purpose](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/purpose) of the location and it will be displayed in the first alert view that is displayed by the os when will ask user for permission.

```
purpose

An application-provided string that describes the reason for using location services.
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *purpose
Discussion

If this property is not nil and the system needs to ask for the user’s consent to use location services, it displays the provided string. You can use this string to explain why your application is using location services.

You must set the value of this property prior to starting any location services. Because the string is ultimately displayed to the user, you should always load it from a localized strings file.
```

Comment: If user has tapped Dont allow. Next time if user again goes to app.Its do not show alertview.

Comment: No that is just for the first time when the app attempts to access location services. Each time you have to check for the CLAuthorizationStatus and alert user according to it

Comment: their is no other method no enable the services programmatically?

Comment: Just if you use undocumented api, but the app will be rejected from the store.

Comment: @ Terente Ionut Alexandru: ok.. thanx

Comment: Can we change the text message in  alertview  when it appears for first time?